# How to get UTC TimeZone DisplayName .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, timezone

I set a winforms combobox with the time zones DisplayName:

```
        var zoneList = TimeZoneInfo
            .GetSystemTimeZones()
            .Where(z => z.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes == 0)
            .Select(z => z.DisplayName);
```

It shows a list like this:

```
    ... 
    (UTC-01:00) Azores 
    (UTC-01:00) Cabo Verde Is. 
    (UTC) Casablanca 
    (UTC) Co-ordinated Universal Time 
    (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London 
    (UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik 
    (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna 
    ...
```

I want to sent the default item to `(UTC) Co-ordinated Universal Time`. However, `TimeZoneInfo.Utc.DisplayName` returns `UTC`. It is unusual because the upper enumeration shows different DisplayName.

`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC")` also returns "UTC".
`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("(UTC) Co-ordinated Universal Time")` and `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Co-ordinated Universal Time")` do not work.

How to get the localized string that corresponds to shown in the enumeration `(UTC) Co-ordinated Universal Time`?

The only solution I can figure out is to store the string `"(UTC) Co-ordinated Universal Time"`, but I'm afraid the upper list may change in different localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- The `DisplayName` is not the ID.  Only the values returned by the `Id` property are suitable for use with the `FindSystemTimeZoneById` method.
- For your dropdown list, you should show the `DisplayName`, but you should *store* only the `Id`.
- The `DisplayName`, `StandardName` and `DaylightName` properties are localized *by the operating system*, not by the globalization features of the .NET Framework.
- The IDs will *always* be in English.  They will never change for localization.
- You should *never* show the IDs to the end-user or interpret them in any particular way.  There are many different conflicting conventions used, and some that are just made up.  See the section on Windows time zones in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for some examples.
- "Coordinated" is a single non-hyphenated word.  These are correct in Windows, so I think you must have added the hyphen yourself.
- Recognize that the offsets shown in the display names are just the base offsets.  They do not indicate whether or not the time zone adjusts for daylight saving time or not.  Nor do the offsets in this list change when daylight saving time is in effect.
- You are correct that `TimeZoneInfo.Utc.DisplayName == "UTC"`, and so does `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC").DisplayName`.  However, the UTC entry returned by `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` has the full form of the display name: `"(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time"`.  Therefore, if you're displaying a dropdown list by enumerating the results from `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`, then you can just use the results as-is.

  But if you want to get that display name directly, you will either have to do this:

  ```
  string s = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().First(x => x.Id == "UTC").DisplayName;
  ```

  Or, this:

  ```
  string key = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\UTC";
  string s = Registry.GetValue(key, "Display", null) as string;
  ```

  Again, remember that all localization of time zone display names is done by the operating system.  Therefore, this approach works fine for Windows desktop applications, but doesn't make a whole lot of sense for web apps.  Also, if your application supports multiple languages internally, you won't be able to rely on .NET Globalization for any time zone display names.  In that scenario, you will need to provide your own source of display names, perhaps in a .resx file, or you can look into using my [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) library.

Comment: Matt, thank you for the perfect answer. Thank you also for the TimeZoneNames library.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I found the answer by printing the time zone's Id.

The desired string is printed with:

```
      TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"); // Wrong
```

**Edit:**
As Matt Johnson noted, the above code shows the London time zone.

Here is another try:

```
      TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().First(t=>t.Id=="UTC").DisplayName
```

Comment: That's London, not UTC.

Comment: @MattJohnson you are right. Anyway, it is enough close and I may use it instead of the Coordinated universal time. Does London time zone may differ than UTC? Does the upper code works in all  cases?

Comment: No, it's not close enough.  London uses UTC/GMT for most of the year, but during daylight saving time (aka "British Summer Time") it is UTC+01:00.